# Magento 2: How to login with Facebook Rest API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, facebook, social

I'm building Rest API and I have to make login with social media.

I found that there are extensions that used for that but what if I want to build API for mobile application.

How to do that.

Comment: Have you get solution for login facebook API. I am looking for same. I have tried but not working.

Comment: any soluction on this?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook login behave is different based on platform Please check below link that are help you.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: Have you any idea about login facebook API. I am looking for same. I have tried but not working.